# Order columns in TableView

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

I want to my **TableView** to remember an order of columns. 

For example I have a table with 3 columns: `Id, Name, Age` and I changing position columns `Name` and `Age`. After this I close window with this table.

Next I open this window again and columns still are in order `Id, Name, Age`, not in `Id, Age, Name`. The same result is when I changing a width of columns. How can I *"remember"* state of TableView?

View is written in fxml file but controllers and the other stuff is in java project.

Answer (score 0):

Since your view is defined by fxml it will always be presented the way you created it there. If you want to change the order of those columns you need to do it by the controller.

I suggest creating some kind of config-file to store those view settings. When starting the view, the settings may be read and applied.

Comment: The whole TableView must be created in controller or only TableColumns?

Comment: Only the TableColumns need to be added by the controller.
I dont have access to my environment right now, but if i remember right TableView.getColumns() returns a ObservableList which may be used to store the order.